# How to read the xml file and write to the dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I really need help. I have an xml file with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Head xmlns="http://www.sample-package.org">
    <Number>748</Number>
    <Number_confirm>977</Number_confirm>
    <Positions>
        <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
    </Positions>
    <Positions>
        <Product_id>168813</Product_id>
    </Positions>
</Head>
```

I need add a key and value to the dictionary (N and "Number"), (id and Product_id), but need do this without a linq, like:

```
//load xml from url
doc.Load(temp);

var root = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Head");
var documents = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
for (int i = 0; i <root.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < root[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {

        var element = root[i].ChildNodes[j];
        InfoManager.MessageBox("element:{0}", element.Value);
        var document = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        document.Add("N", element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Number"));
        document.Add("NC", element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Number_confirm"));
        documents.Add("ID",
        element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Product_id"));
        documents.Add(document);

    }

}
```

Now element.Attributes = null, MessageBox shows element empty, i cant see Attributes/Element and does not add all the elements to the dictionary. How can I fix it??

Comment: The values you are looking for are not attributes. An xml attribute would be like `<tag attribute="value"></tag>`. I'd suggest you read up on XML and the respective .net classes. You may find it easier to use XPath expressions to get the information you are looking for, so you might want to explore that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** The `element` does not have any value. To get the numbers you are looking for, you will have to use `element.InnerText` as in:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("element:{0}", element.InnerText));
```

**2)** Then in the `document.Add`-Statements, you are trying to access the Attributes, but there are no Attributes on your elements.

An example for an attribute would be:

```
<Number MyAttribute="additionalInfo">67</Number>
```

**3)** You have a typo in one of your `document.Add`-Statements. You accidently typed document**s** once.

**4)** In your second loop you loop through all the elements in the root (Head). So you enter the loop 4 times and each time you got a different element, but you try to add all the values in each iteration. You want to actually have a List of `KeyValuePairs` like the in following:

```
var root = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Head");
var documents = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < root[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
  {
    var element = root[i].ChildNodes[j];
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("element:{0}", element.InnerText));
    var document = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(element.Name, element.InnerText);
    documents.Add(document);
  }
}
```

Now the dictionary equals to the structure your xml has: An object (Head) has a List of KeyValuePairs ("Number" pairs with "748", "Number_confirm" pairs with "977", etc.)

---

As your comment suggests, if your xml could look as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Head xmlns="http://www.sample-package.org">
    <Number>748</Number>
    <Number_confirm>977</Number_confirm>
    <Positions> <!-- Note: two numbers in one Positions-element -->
        <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
        <Product_id>168813</Product_id>
    </Positions>
</Head>
```

..then you will have to add another loop to go deeper and change the following:

```
..
var element = root[i].ChildNodes[j];
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("element:{0}", element.InnerText));

string numbers = string.Empty;
for(int z = 0; z < element.ChildNodes.Count; z++)
{
  numbers += element.ChildNodes[z].InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
}

var document = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(element.Name, numbers);
documents.Add(document);
..
```

Alltough I recommend, that you create a class with the properties like in the xml so you can load the xml internal and print/alter it at your will.

Comment: First you create document as an empty KeyValuePair, immediately after that you create a new KeyValuePair with values for key and value, so you could omit the first constructor call.

Comment: @StefanIllner, you're right, thanks. I initially let it be for a more step by step-like code, but I merged those statements now.

Comment: if element <Positions> have several items like `<Positions>
        <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
        <Product_id>168813</Product_id> ` then i see in console text (2442168813) all element in 1 line. how make code with each key and value in each line (2442 and new line of value 168813)

Comment: To add a new line to a string you should use `Environment.NewLine`. In your case, you probably should print a new line in between your numbers, alltough without code I cannot know, where the new problem lies. However If an answer solves the problem in the original question, I kindly ask you to accept an answer by ticking the check mark or edit your question to address further problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use XmlDocument and convert it into JSON object.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(*XML FILE PATH*);
string XML_JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(XML_JSON);
var XML_OBJECT = jsonObject["Head"];

JToken number = (JToken) XML_OBJECT["Number"]
JToken numberConfirm = (JToken) XML_OBJECT["Number_confirm"];
JArray positions = (JArray) XML_OBJECT["Positions"];
```

Then Iterate it the way you wanted to be added in your dictionary.

FYI It doesn't have any attributes in your XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The Xml document you provide has <Head> as the root element, so the foreach loop will always iterate over exactly one element, as well as the list of dictionaries.

But probably that was just a short example. To get what you desire, you can find the elements you want using XPath like this:

```
doc.Load(temp);

XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("pkg", "http://www.sample-package.org");
var root = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Head");
var documents = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
{
    var head = root[i];
    var document = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    document.Add("N", head.SelectSingleNode("/pkg:Head/pkg:Number", nsMgr).InnerText);
    document.Add("NC", head.SelectSingleNode("/pkg:Head/pkg:Number_confirm", nsMgr).InnerText);
    document.Add("ID", head.SelectSingleNode("/pkg:Head/pkg:Positions/pkg:Product_id", nsMgr).InnerText);
    documents.Add(document);
}
```